# How to use autoLayout to self-sizing cell when there is a tableview in the cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I can not confirm the embed `tableView`'s height.
I use the self-sizing cell in the embed tableView, so I think the embed `tableView` will know it's height itself.So I make a constraint like this:

```
    [tableView remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker* make) {
        make.top.equalTo(wkself.feedView.bottom);
        make.left.equalTo(wkself.userNameLabel);
        make.width.equalTo(@(TQ_FEEDBACK_TABLEVIEW_WIDTH));
        make.height.greaterThanOrEqualTo(@0);
        make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.bottom).offset(-10);
    }];
```

but this result is that the embed `tableView`'s height is always 0.I don't know how to deal with this.

what's more, if the embed tableView have `tableHeaderView` or `tableFooterView`, how do I deal with this?

Comment: Don't use nested table views. You probably want to use sections or a collection view. You won't be able to achieve what you want using nested table views. A table view is a scrolling view. It knows its content size but the size must be given externally. That's why self-sizing cannot work.

Comment: Thank you very much! I search much information but nothing can help me. What I want to implement is like comments in twitter,each twitter has some comments. What do you think is the most elegant way to implement this? Thank you very much!